# How to show metro bundler in new terminal when execute react-native run-android?

Tags: react-native, ubuntu-16.04, metro-bundler

the command react-native run-android not opening metro bundler in new terminal on ubuntu. it only show starting js server and other react-native messages, and the app run normally.

when I tried it on windows or mac, metro bundler always opened in new terminal whenever I run react-native run-android and the port is available.

I am using ubuntu 16.04, react-native 0.57.8

what should I add to the command to make it behave like on windows or mac?

I am expecting it will run metro bundler in new terminal on ubuntu just like on windows or mac. thanks.